# AutoML: out of memory on small training file

Tags: h2o

I am attempting to run H2OAutoML on a 2.7MB training CSV on a system with 4GB RAM using the python API and it is running out of memory.

The error messages I am encountering are either:

```
h2o_ubuntu_started_from_python.out:
02-17 17:57:25.063 127.0.0.1:54321       27097  FJ-3-15   INFO: Stopping XGBoost training because of timeout
#
# There is insufficient memory for the Java Runtime Environment to continue.
# Native memory allocation (mmap) failed to map 247463936 bytes for committing reserved memory.
# An error report file with more information is saved as:
# /home/ubuntu/h20.ai/h2o-3.28.0.2/hs_err_pid27097.log
```

or

```
03:37:07.509: XRT_1_AutoML_20200217_030816 [DRF XRT (Extremely Randomized Trees)] failed: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
```

in the output of the python depending on the exact crash instance I look at.

My init is:

```
h2o.init(max_mem_size='3G',min_mem_size='2G',jvm_custom_args=["-Xmx3g"])
```

Though I have tried with:
`h2o.init()`

My H2OAutoML call is:

```
H2OAutoML(nfolds=5,max_models=20, max_runtime_secs_per_model=600, seed=1,project_name =project_name)
aml.train(x=x, y=y, training_frame=train,validation_frame=test)
```

These are the server stats:

```
H2O cluster uptime:         02 secs
H2O cluster timezone:       Etc/UTC
H2O data parsing timezone:  UTC
H2O cluster version:        3.28.0.2
H2O cluster version age:    27 days
H2O cluster name:           H2O_from_python_ubuntu_htq5aj
H2O cluster total nodes:    1
H2O cluster free memory:    3 Gb
H2O cluster total cores:    2
H2O cluster allowed cores:  2
H2O cluster status:         accepting new members, healthy
H2O connection url:         http://127.0.0.1:54321
H2O connection proxy:       {'http': None, 'https': None}
H2O internal security:      False
H2O API Extensions:         Amazon S3, XGBoost, Algos, AutoML, Core V3, TargetEncoder, Core V4
Python version:             3.6.9 final
```

Does this sound right? Am I not able to run 20 models?

I can run this just fine setting the max_models=10. This takes about 60 min.

Are there guidelines for the amount of RAM needed for a given max_models and filesize?

Comment: 4 GB isn't really enough memory to do anything anymore these days.  You can solve your problem for under $0.20 / hr with an m5.xlarge EC2 instance with 16 GB of RAM.

Answer (score 0):

Connect to the Flow interface, running at 127.0.0.1:54321.

There is a section there where you can view the remaining memory. You can also see what models and data frames are being created. You have `max_runtime_secs_per_model` set to 600, and say 10 models takes an hour, so if you check in every 5-10 minutes, you can get an idea of how much memory each model is taking up.

Your h2o.init() response looks fine. The guideline was to have 3-4 times the dataset size free. If your data is only 2.7MB, then this should not be a concern. Though if you have a lot of categorical columns, especially with a lot of choices, then they can take up more memory than you expect.

The memory used by a model can vary quite a lot, depending on the parameters chosen. Again, it is best to look on Flow, to see what parameters AutoML is choosing for you.

If it is simply the case that 10 models will fit in memory, and 20 models won't, and you don't want to take manual control of the parameters, then you could do batches of 10 models, and save after each hour. (Choose a different `seed` for each run.)